# How to set up a header block

Tags: theming

I am trying to create a header block that I can use for multiple page.tpl.php files so I created a new block, set it to be displayed in the header region and copied the HTML from my non-drupal version of the site.

```
<div class="header row">
<header class="container">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <h1 class="logo">Muse</h1>
    <!-- TODO: comment to disable registration ~ Eric Farley -->
     <?php 
        if ($main_menu){
            print theme('links__system_main_menu', array(
              'links' => $main_menu,
              'attributes' => array(
                'class' => array('registerLnk'),
              )
            )); //#main-menu -->
            } 
        ?>
  </div>
</header>
```

However drupal stripes out all of my divs and classes and replaces them with a bunch of crap I didn't ask it to add.

```
<div class="region region-header">
<div id="block-block-1" class="block block-block contextual-links-region">

<h2>Header</h2>
<div class="contextual-links-wrapper contextual-links-processed">
  <a class="contextual-links-trigger" href="#">Configure</a>
  <ul class="contextual-links">
    <li class="block-configure first last">
      <a href="/admin/structure/block/manage/block/1/configure?destination=node/1">Configure block</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <p>Muse</p>
</div>
```

As you can see the code that drupal outputs is nothing like the code I told it to output, and therefor does not render even close to correctly. How do I make drupal do what I told it to and render the html I provided instead of that crap it's rendering?

Comment: What input format are you using for your block?

Comment: The Text Format of the Block body is set to Filtered HTML.

Comment: Change the text format to full html (create a new format if necessary). In that format ensure the requisite tag aren't being stripped. The contextual links markup is visible only to users who have access to that module. It's better practice to put php code in a module or your theme template file  rather than adding it via the editor ui. It makes for code that's easier to find, read, and write. If you don't like the wrapper markup that the block is producing, you can override that globally or per block via a block template override. Also see the Menu block module.